# Displaying the zero value as well as the final value in an array list

Tags: java, arrays

I'm writing a present value calculator in java where the user enters the future amount, the inflation rate, and the term in months. I can get it to calculate correctly, but I need to display the full term including zero, so if they enter 24 months, I need to display 0 - 24 not 0 - 23. How do I account for the zero value?

Comment: we don't know without some code to look at.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array with a size of 25. That will give you 0-24.

Answer (score 0):

That is a good question.  When you are calculating future value, you need to remember that you have a starting point that is always at time zero.  And then at the end of the first time period, you have accumulated some interested, which is posted at the end of time 1 (etc) and that becomes the new beginning about.  The program's array notation begins with zero, so that is an advantage for your calculation.  If you are calculating with repeated iterations, then you will have to use an array size that begins with the beginning amount at time zero, and ends with time period 25.  That would be a 0 to 26 array.  I've done that calculation, by the way, and I don't recommend doing it in iterations that sum again and again to create a cumulative sum, because you may run into rounding errors.  Therefore, what you want to do is use one of the standard formulas and calculate each period individually, according to the formula.  If you use the formula correct, that will be faster and more correct.   Be sure to divide the annual interest rate by the number of periods to get the per-period rate, (i.e.: monthly is rate/12) and be sure to multiply the number of periods by the number of periods per year (i.e.: Periods = years*12 if and only if your monthly rate is rate/12)  There is an easier way to say that, but if you are looking at the formula and an explanation of the formula you will see what I am talking about.